# Why was Rukia's head covered when she was escorted to/from the Repentance Cell?

Tags: bleach

When Rukia was transported to the Repentance Cell after the use of the Sokyoku for her execution was authorized her head was covered with a white cloth. and i recall alter on when she is escoted to the execution ground her head is covered aswell

What i don't get is why? I get the feeling it may be something to do with a Japanese Tradition because when Ichigo's team got back and Orihime was telling Tatsuki about what she did during the break i seem to recall Tatsuki assuming that Orihime just went to a town that was themed like feudal japan.

Also it's not like Rukia wouldn't know the location of the cell since how many tall white towers are there in the Seireitei which overlook Sokyoku hill.

so why was Rukia's head covered when she was escorted to/from the Repentance Cell?

Answer (score 1):

Covering a prisoners head is a good way to "dehumanize" them and it's a good way to try to prevent riots and escapes since people don't know who the prisoner is and the prisoner themselves cant see.

Answer (score 0):

This is an act called [Hooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooding) (Wikipedia). It is often used as a form of torture, but also be for the purpose of hiding the prisoner's facial expressions to try and dehumanize the prisoner, as [user30104 said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/40708/34906).

According to the International Committee of the Red Cross:

> Page 12 of the [ICRC report on the Treatment by the Coalition Forces of Prisoners of War](https://web.archive.org/web/20091016005519/http://www.derechos.org/nizkor/us/doc/icrc-prisoner-report-feb-2004.pdf)
>
> [This report contains rather graphic descriptions of violence]

hooding is used to disorientate and prevent the victim from breathing freely. Hooding can increase the anxiety of the prisoner, and it also allows the prisoner escorts/interrogators to remain anonymous.